# Sequence numbering in Word 2010

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I'm using MS Word 2010, and I have multiple documents with headings and sequence numbering. How can I change a number so that the rest of the numbers automatically change in the rest of the document?

Answer (score 0):

you could try creating a master document, and adding all of your existing documents to it.
then, changing the sequence of one document would theoretically change the sequence in all other documents as well.
http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/word-help/create-a-master-document-and-subdocuments-HP005187002.aspx